# Performing task for a particular datatype alone in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below:

[image]

Here's the code to build this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['A12', 'B18', 'C78'],
                   'Age': [55, 45, 58],
                   'Hobbies': ['Movies', 'Walking', 'Travelling'],
                   'Salary': [60000, 55000, 85000]})
```

I need to pass the entire dataframe in a loop where is perform the mean function for the integer data type alone (in my example its age and salary) leaving the rest of datatype as it is. Could anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: As shown in the image, if you know the columns names, I guess you can explicitly define the columns on which mean needs to be performed.

Comment: This is just an example in my real time data I have more than 250+ column names bro.

Comment: In that case , you can add a condition to your function to check for datatype of column and perform mean only of it matches Integer datatype. for e.g `if type(column[0])==type(1):` perform mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) + [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

Select numeric series and *then* calculate the mean:

```
res = df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).mean()

print(res)

# Age          52.666667
# Salary    66666.666667
# dtype: float64
```

To strictly include *only* `int` series, so that `float` series are *excluded*, you can use:

```
res = df.select_dtypes(include=['int']).mean()
```